# .NET 5 Web API: Storing data per request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

When getting a request in any action of any controller, I look at the jwt know which user is requesting and lookup the user in the database to get some user-data that I want to use throughout the application. E.g. which departments the user belongs to or the users preferred language.

Now I could create a object which wraps these information and send it down the layers and pass it to every method that likes to use some of this data. But I like the data to be available to every method throughout the application without passing it in every method. Like e.g. dependency injection (Seems to late at that point) or something else I can get access to that data quickly.

Any advice of how to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with the Items property on the HttpContext. By using it you can store data during a single request. The only downside with this approach is that every service needs to have access to the HttpContext to read the values. Values can be added to the Items Dictionary as shown below

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    //
    public void OnGet()
    {
        HttpContext.Items.Add("Key", new RequestInfo { Key = "RequestKey" });
    }
}
class RequestInfo
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

You can then access the value by registering the IHttpContextAccessor to the IServiceCollection and then using Constructor injection to use the HttpContext in your service so that you can work with the Items Dictionary.

```
public class Service
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _htp;
    public Service(IHttpContextAccessor http)
    {
        _htp = http;
    }
    public void Log()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((RequestInfo)_htp.HttpContext.Items["Key"]).Key);
    }
}
```